# jQuery - Selecting an element within $(this) not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

So I have this HTML code

```html
<section class="panel">
    <header class="panel-heading" id="tills">
        <div class="panel-actions">
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-caret-down"></a>
        </div>
        <h2 class="panel-title">Tills</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="app-next"><button>Next</button></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am trying to change the class of `<a>` within `<div class="panel-actions">`.

```js
$(".panel").on("click", '.app-next button', function(){
    var panel;
    var target;

    panel =  $(this).closest('.panel');       
    target = $(panel).closest('.fa-caret-down');
    console.log(panel); //Returns OK.
    console.log(target); //Returns <button>
});
```

Why is `console.log(target)` not returning `<a href="#" class="fa fa-caret-down">` ?

Comment: can u just create a fiddle?

Comment: First you're finding the closest `.panel`, but then from there, the anchor isn't the `closest`, it's a descendant element, so you want `find()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` looks for ancestors up the DOM tree, but you want to look for descendents of `.panel`

Use `find()` to look for descendents.

```
$(".panel").on("click", '.app-next button', function(){
    var $panel =$(this).closest('.panel');
    var $target = $panel.find('.fa-caret-down');        
    console.log($target); //Returns <button>
});
```

Note that it is redundant and inefficient to wrap an existing jQuery object in `$()`. In your code `panel` is already a jQuery object that can use jQuery methods

Answer (score 0):

`fa-caret-down` is children of the `panel` and the closest do not select the selector that way, the closest method select closest parent div. You may use find method instead:

```
target = $(panel).find('.fa-caret-down');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read how [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) works.

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

You can use [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(panel).find('a.fa-caret-down');
```

Answer (score 0):

.closest() only travels upwards, not downwards.

The code you're looking for is:

```
target = $('.fa-caret-down',panel);
```

This is equivalent to saying "look for .fa-caret-down inside panel"